# Supplying function arguments for operations performed on data.table subsets created by `by`

Tags: r, arguments, data.table

Data tables in R have three (main) components: `DT[i, j, by]`.

I am creating subsets of my data.table **DT** using the `by` functionality, which returns subsets of my data to `j`, where I can perform operations on them. I within each of the new subsets, I can specify the columns I want to use in `j`.

From [the documentation](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html) (slightly altered by me):

> `DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=., .SDcols=...]` - applies fun (=mean) to all
>   columns specified in .SDcols while grouping by the columns specified
>   in by.

This is great functionality!

I would like to know if it is possible to supply arguments to the function being used in `j` - in this case: `mean`?

The function `mean` can take the following inputs:

```
mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)
```

How can I use `mean` within the `j` section **AND** apply, for example, `na.rm = TRUE`?

---

On a side note, I did have a similar problem regarding the `Reduce`
function, which applied a functions to a data sets recursiely. The best idea I found was to create a custom version of the function to apply, so something like:

```
my_mean <- function(Data) {

    output <- mean(Data, na.rm = TRUE)

    return(output)
}
```

then using the example above, I would perform:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, my_mean), by=., .SDcols=...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can pass the extra arguments into lapply:

```
DT = data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4,NA),y=runif(5),z=c(1,1,1,2,2))
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean,na.rm=T), by=z]
```

Comment: Worth noting that this has nothing to do with `data.table`; see `?lapply`.

Comment: It works similarly with `Reduce`, sending the values in each group defined by `by`.